# What does Realization mean?

Tags: statistics

I read a paper.  It states that " For data sets, we used 10 realizations for parameter selection and 20 other realizations for parameter selection.

Does realization in this case mean simulation ?

Thanks

Comment: This is better asked on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=define%20realizations&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=realization&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=ZLCgT8zXF4GO2AWrm6msCQ&ved=0CB4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=a9c9eb23d1f4dcb8&biw=1240&bih=764

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provided either (i) a link to the paper or (ii) more context, because at the moment it isn't clear what the sentence refers to.

My best guess is that it means 'realization' in the sense of 'a particular series that might be generated by a specified random process'.

Comment: The paper is the [A Hybrid Novelty Score and Its Use in Keystroke Dynamics-Based User Authentication](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320309001502). The context is in section 3 of the paper.